# Create UDP-like library in C

Tags: c

I am looking to implement some kind of transmission protocol in C, to use on a custom hardware. I have the ability to send and receive through RF, but I need to rely in some protocol that validates the package integrity sent/received, so I though it would be a good idea to implement some kind of UDP library.

Of course, if there is any way that I can modify the existing implementations for UDP or TCP so it works over my RF device it would be of great help. The only thing that I think it needs to be changed is the way that a single bit is sent, if I could change that on the UDP library (sys/socket.h) it would save me a lot of time.

Comment: Which particular hardware, which processor, which operating system, which C compiler, .... Please edit your question to improve it.

Comment: no operative system, just a PIC 18F4550, I am not sure of the compiler, I will investigate it.

Comment: If you want a full IP stack, you might reconsider your hardware choice (or be prepared to spend years of work)

Comment: I don't pretend to write a multi-hardware compatible library, I just need some way to segment data and validate packages, discard them when invalid, resynchronize, I understand it's not easy but it's not that hard either when I already have the physical layer working. change the hardware is out of the question, it's a project for the university that it's already working and approved, the only missing part is to be able to do data resilience.

Comment: But then it has nothing to do with UDP.... or with sockets. You just want to implement a serial protocol, and that becomes a different question.

Comment: I never mean to implement UDP by myself, that is why the title says UDP-like, and not UDP. and I think it's related to it, since UDP in a very high level of abstraction is just that, data segmentation, validation and discarded when corrupted

Comment: Nothing in common with UDP (no need of data packets). You just want some serial protocol, and you might want some way of validating it. USB or X25 might be as inspirational as UDP.

Comment: Can you describe your custom hardware ? How much memory does it have is pretty important to know.

Comment: What is the RF device you are using, and what sort of data are you trying to send? - i.e. is it real time, full-duplex, large or small packets etc. It sounds like you want a link layer protocol. TCP/IP sits above this in the stack.

Comment: hello, regarding the hardware is only 512k of eprom memory. what examples of link layer protocols do you suggest me to check?

Answer (score 2):

[UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) does not exist in standard [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) or C11.

It is generally part of some [Internet Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol) layer. These are very complex software (as soon as you want some performance).

I would suggest to use some *existing* [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) kernel (e.g. Linux) and to write a network driver (e.g. for the [Linux kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel)) for your device. Life is too short to write a competitive UDP like layer (that could take you dozens of years).

---

#### addenda

Apparently, the mention of UDP in the question is confusing. Per your comments (which should go inside the question) you just want some serial protocol on a small 8 bits PIC 18F4550 microcontroller (32Kbytes ROM + 2Kbytes RAM). Without knowing additional constraints, I would suggest a tiny "textual" like protocol (e.g. in ASCII lines, no more than 128 bytes per line, `\n` terminated ....) and I would put some simple hex checksum inside it. In the 1980s [Hayes modems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set) had such things.

What you should then do is define and document the protocol first (e.g. as [BNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) syntax of the message lines), then implement it (probably with buffering and finite state automaton techniques). You might invent some message format like e.g. `DOFOO?123,456%BE53` followed by a newline, meaning do the command `DOFOO` with arguments `123` then `456` and hex checksum `BE53`

Comment: "Life is too short to write a competitive UDP like layer (that could take you dozens of years).
" well said

Comment: install a linux is something out of the question, this is the system I am using: https://sites.google.com/site/proyectosroboticos/nrf24l01/nrf24l01-18f4550, there is no chance I can ever run a linux on that. I have been looking around and there is ways to create a driver for the inet input/output functions, however it's quite complex indeed.

Comment: actually UDP in itself is very simple. Because it hardly has any functionality on top of IP, whereas TCP is a lot more complex. Of course if the IP layer also needs to be implemented then it is difficult. But UDP basically only adds the source port and destination port to allow multiple UDP communications to occur at once.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck: agreed that UDP is very close to IP. But IP is quite complex if you dive into details, want close compatibility with existing things, and need routing, packet & congestion management, etc etc.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I did not say that IP is simple, I said UDP is simple. And even then, the BSD implemenation of IP, TCP, UDP, ICMP can be downloaded from the internet. No need to implement yourself.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck: will BSD implementation of IP fit on a 16 bits microcontroller with 32Kbytes of ROM and 2 kbytes of RAM?

Comment: where did the op state he has only 2k of RAM, you mentioned it but not the OP. the stack in itself is not that large code wise speaking. http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.37/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c But IP can handle segments that receive out of order till 64k, so you need more a lot more than 64k in your device. For small devices your suggestion is perfectly fine.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck: the OP commented about a PIC 18F4550. I downvoted the question because that essential information is missing in the question text. Feel free to downvote the question too!